# Grep for ":" in one instance, but not ":" in another

Tags: grep, bbedit

I need to find `:` when occurring after an **alpha char**, but NOT when its before or after an integer, and am having trouble setting that grep.

In the following example, I only want to replace the `:` after *Creation Time* with a *TAB* and *NOT* where it occurs between numbers...

> Creation Time: 10/3/02 6:48:34 PM

I am using `BBEdit`. Any advice would be gratefully accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know BBEdit, but this sort of stuff is really easy in Perl. For example:

```
echo "Creation Time: 10/3/02 6:48:34 PM" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([^\d]):/$1\t/g; print $_'
```

or if you have a file called `stuff.txt` with the string in it, you can type:

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([^\d]):/$1\t/g; print $_' stuff.txt
```

The `-n` flag in perl causes it to loop through a file or STDIN, and the `-e` part of the options runs the program in the quotes. When looping through the input, the line is stored in the variable `$_`. So what I'm doing is replacing the contents of `$_`, matching any part that is not a digit (the part in the parentheses) followed by a `:` with the matched part (`$1` is equal to the part inside the first parentheses) and a tab character. After the replacing, I print the modified `$_`.

So you can try

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([^\d]):/$1\t/g; print $_' stuff.txt > check.txt
```

and look at `check.txt` to make sure I didn't lead you astray, and then copy it over.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for the chime-in. However, when I cd to the folder where a test file lives, and run the above string as "perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([^\d]):/$1\t/g; print $_' 000001.txt" (without the quotes), there is odd output in OSX Terminal (a portion of the text in one of the lines in the file). Moreover, I am unsure (not knowing Perl) where I would input or alter to allow for a TAB to be inserted after the alphachar-plus-colon. ??

Comment: So perl by itself will print it's output to the terminal. If you follow that string by `> test.txt`, the output will instead go into `test.txt`. Then you can look at the file to make sure it's right before moving it to `000001.txt`. You can look at [this, for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file).

Comment: I guess long story short, try `perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([^\d]):/$1\t/g; print $_' 000001.txt > test.txt` and let me know what's in `test.txt`. (Note, this will overwrite `test.txt` if it already exists, so pick a different name if you don't want to do that.)

Comment: That absolutely did the trick! Thank you very much indeed for your assistance. The resulting text.txt opened in Excel with data in appropriate columns as expected.

Comment: BBEdit uses PCRE so that regular expression should work in the app too.